# Too long math "formula" inside the text

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

It's possible that someone already asked it, but I'm unable to find something about so I've to ask again.

I'm having this problem: I will put a math formula inside the text using the `$ $` environment and i need to put some text in the math formula; I can use the `\text{}` command, but I'm trying to keep the math environment style. The problem is that it dosn't go in a new line.
[image: problem]

The image show my problem.

Here the piece of code that is givin me the problem

```
per poi ottenere $Q:=P(\xi_1)\land ...\land P(\xi_m)\land P(-\xi_1)\land ...\land P(-\xi_m)="uno\ stato\ casuale\ si\ stabilizza\ in\ uno\ degli\ stati\ memorizzati\ o\ un\ suo\ opposto".$\\
A questo punto
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show the TeX code?

Comment: added only the piece of code problematic. Is better if I upload the whole text?

Comment: Well, text is text, math is math. You really should treat your text as text using `\text{si stabilizza}`.

Comment: Try taking the string `uno stato casuale si stabilizza in uno degli stati memorizzati o un suo opposto` out of math mode. You'll like the result.

Comment: The problem of `\text` is that it doesn’t allow line breaks. The sentence should be changed to something like (I use english as I don’t know Italian) “per poi ottenere $Q:= ...$ [*where*] $Q$ [*is*] uno stato casuale...”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't type long descriptions in a math formula:

```
per poi ottenere 
$Q:=P(\xi_1)\land\dots\land P(\xi_m)\land P(-\xi_1)\\dots\land P(-\xi_m)=$ 
``\textit{uno stato casuale si stabilizza in uno degli stati memorizzati o un suo opposto}''.

A questo punto
```

Remove `\textit` if you don't need italics.

Don't use `\\` for ending paragraphs either. Note `\dots` for the ellipsis. Remember to have `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

Also quotation marks are

```
 ``  ''
```

not `"`.

The similar text above should have

```
che si stabilizza in~$x$
```

(note the tie for avoiding a line break.

Comment: I don’t agree. You can always typeset text inside math-mode using `\text`, and that don’t break the semantics.

Comment: @T.D. `\text` will not allow line breaks.

Comment: Well, thanks for the other suggestion: quite satisfied with your answer. What I have to use instead of    \\    ?

Comment: @DavideF. A blank line separates paragraphs.